Kotlin Multiplatform: Unresolved reference 'serializer'
I was following the tutorial: Create a multiplatform app using Ktor and SQLDelight.
The problem what I confronted is that the Problems Console told me references are unresolved. But I code the same as the tutorial website letting me know.
These are the errors:
Unresolved reference 'entity'. :3,4,5
Unresolved reference 'RocketLaunch'. :25
Unresolved reference 'Links'. :31
Unresolved reference 'Patch'. :32

First thing I am curious about is that why even 'entity' is unresolved since it is existed at shared/src/commonMain/kotlin/com/jetbrains/spacetutorial/entity. Also why did the file cannot find those serializers since I put a @Serializable each of them in ~/entity/Entity.kt?
I am working on Android Studio. I first thought the error occurs because of the IDE, so I do 'Invalidate and Restart' and 'Sync Project with Gradle Files', but it did not solve the problem.
Another concerns is about Gradle files setting, but I am not sure because I am new using Kotlin; not much idea. Somebody who wants more detail about the code please have a look on my github repository where I push the all code.
If the more information needs to be provided, please let me know.
Thanks for readers and people who answers in advance.
// shared/src/commonMain/kotlin/com/jetbrains/spacetutorial/entity/Entity.kt

import kotlinx.datetime.TimeZone
import kotlinx.datetime.toInstant
import kotlinx.datetime.toLocalDateTime
import kotlinx.serialization.SerialName
import kotlinx.serialization.Serializable

@Serializable
data class RocketLaunch(
    @SerialName("flight_number")
    val flightNumber: Int,
    @SerialName("name")
    val missionName: String,
    @SerialName("date_utc")
    val launchDateUTC: String,
    @SerialName("details")
    val details: String?,
    @SerialName("success")
    val launchSuccess: Boolean?,
    @SerialName("links")
    val links: Links
) {
    var launchYear = launchDateUTC.toInstant().toLocalDateTime(TimeZone.UTC).year
}

@Serializable
data class Links(
    @SerialName("patch")
    val patch: Patch?,
    @SerialName("article")
    val article: String?
)

@Serializable
data class Patch(
    @SerialName("small")
    val small: String?,
    @SerialName("large")
    val large: String?
)


Please [edit] your question and add the relevant code so we can reproduce your problem ourselves. We need to see a [mre]. Links to external sites are not enough.

@Leviathan I first afraid of the large code amount, so I substituted into link. But now I realize providing a code would be helpful. Thank you for letting me know.

The code you provided compiles just fine for me. Can be more more specific which of the above lines produce the problems you see?

@Leviathan Thank you for your interest. It was a small mistake that I did not write a package keyword in Entity.kt, one of my project files. I answered by myself on this question.

I found the problem: the Entity.kt file did not include the code below:
package com.jetbrains.spacetutorial.entity

